# Why can't I draw the player trajectory in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a space simulation game, where a rocket has to go from planet to planet using gravity.

I'm at a point where I want to draw the trajectory of the rocket to help the players. I have wrote some code using the Unity's feature Simulate, but it doesn't work. The game is running fine but the goshObject used to draw the line doesn't move at all and stays bellow the player rocket.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class TrajectoryVisualization : MonoBehaviour
{

    private static Scene TrajectoryScene;
    private static PhysicsScene TrajectoryPhysicsScene;
    private static LineRenderer lineRenderer;

    private static GameObject ghostRocketObj;
    private static List<GameObject> ghostPlanetsObj;
    private static List<GameObject> ghostBoundariesObj;

    [SerializeField] private static int simulationSteps = 50;

    void Start()
    {

        TrajectoryScene = SceneManager.CreateScene("TrajectorySimulation", new CreateSceneParameters(LocalPhysicsMode.Physics2D));
        TrajectoryPhysicsScene = TrajectoryScene.GetPhysicsScene();
        
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        addPlanetsToSimulation();
        addRocketToSimulation();
        addBoundariesToSimulation();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Physics.autoSimulation = false;

        Debug.Log("START SIMULATION");

        ghostRocketObj.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position;
        Rigidbody2D ghostVelocity = ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        ghostVelocity.velocity = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;

        List<Vector3> pathPoints = new List<Vector3>();

        for (int i = 0; i < simulationSteps; i++)
        {
            Gravity.calculateGravity(ghostPlanetsObj, ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(), true);
            TrajectoryPhysicsScene.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
            pathPoints.Add(ghostRocketObj.transform.position);
        }
        

        lineRenderer.positionCount = simulationSteps;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(pathPoints.ToArray());

        Debug.Log("END SIMULATION");

        Physics.autoSimulation = true;

    }

    private void addPlanetsToSimulation()
    {

        ghostPlanetsObj = new List<GameObject>();

        //Add planets to simulation scene
        foreach (GameObject planet in ListPlanets.getPlanetsObject())
        {
            GameObject ghostplanetObj = Instantiate(planet, planet.transform.position, planet.transform.rotation);
            ghostplanetObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
            SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(ghostplanetObj, TrajectoryScene);
            ghostPlanetsObj.Add(ghostplanetObj);
        }

    }

    private void addRocketToSimulation()
    {
        //Add planets to simulation scene
        ghostRocketObj = Instantiate(gameObject, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
        ghostRocketObj.tag = "RocketSimulation";
        ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
        ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<Animator>().enabled = false;
        ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<Rotation>().enabled = false;
        ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<RocketThrust>().enabled = false;
        ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<PlayerInput>().enabled = false;
        ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<TrajectoryVisualization>().enabled = false;
        ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<AudioSource>().enabled = false;
        ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<Position>().enabled = false;
        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(ghostRocketObj, TrajectoryScene);
    }

    private void addBoundariesToSimulation()
    {

        ghostBoundariesObj = new List<GameObject>();

        foreach (GameObject boundary in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Boundary"))
        {
            GameObject ghostBoundaryObj = Instantiate(boundary, boundary.transform.position, boundary.transform.rotation);
            ghostBoundaryObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
            SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(ghostBoundaryObj, TrajectoryScene);
            ghostBoundariesObj.Add(ghostBoundaryObj);
        }
    }


    public static void createNewPlanetSimulation(GameObject newPlanet)
    {
        GameObject ghostplanetObj = Instantiate(newPlanet, newPlanet.transform.position, newPlanet.transform.rotation);
        ghostplanetObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(ghostplanetObj, TrajectoryScene);
        ghostPlanetsObj.Add(ghostplanetObj);
    }

}
```

Here's the code calculating gravity:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Rigidbody2D planetAttractor;

    [SerializeField] private static float G = 4.0f;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rocketPlayer;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D planetOrigin;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        planetAttractor = planetOrigin;
        Scoring.reference = planetOrigin.name;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        calculateGravity(ListPlanets.getPlanetsObject(), rocketPlayer, false);
    }

    public static void calculateGravity(List<GameObject> planets, Rigidbody2D rocket, bool isSimulation)
    {
        float smallestDistance = Vector2.Distance(planets[0].GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position, rocket.position);

        foreach (GameObject planet in planets)
        {
            Rigidbody2D tmpBody = planet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

            float distance = Vector2.Distance(tmpBody.position, rocket.position);
            if (distance <= smallestDistance)
            {

                planetAttractor = tmpBody;
                smallestDistance = distance;
            }
        }

        float massProduct = planetAttractor.mass*rocket.mass*G;

        Vector2 direction = planetAttractor.position - rocket.position;
        float distanceBetween = direction.magnitude;

        float unScaledforceMagnitude = massProduct/Mathf.Pow(distanceBetween,2);
        float forceMagnitude = G*unScaledforceMagnitude;

        Vector2 forceDirection = direction.normalized;
        Vector2 forceVector = forceDirection*forceMagnitude;

        Debug.Log("forceDirection: " + forceDirection);
        Debug.Log("forceMagnitude: " + forceMagnitude);
        Debug.Log("rocket.position: " + rocket.position);
        Debug.Log("rocket.velocity: " + rocket.velocity);

        rocket.AddForce(forceVector);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

EDIT

I have noticed is that any modification to the Rigidbody2D of the ghostRocketRb aren't applied even :
`ghostRocketRb.position = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my issue, I making a 2D game and was using a 3D scene ...

The trick was to use

```
PhysicsScene2D TrajectoryPhysicsScene;
```

instead of

```
PhysicsScene TrajectoryPhysicsScene;
```

I'm also adding extra information, according to some Unity devs:

- To create the ghost, scene is it actualy better to populate it using
  `SceneManager.SetActiveScene(...)` then set back the game scene to the active one than to use `MoveGameObjectToScene` that takes a lot of ressources.
- Use `simulationMode` instead of `autoSimulation`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what has been observed, it appears that the TrajectoryVisualization script may be responsible for the issue at hand. To be more specific, there seems to be a problem occurring in the Update method of this script. The root of the problem stems from simulating physics in a different scene (known as TrajectoryPhysicsScene) while neglecting to adjust and synchronize with positioning within the line renderer.

To resolve this, one must ensure that updates to position within the simulated physics scene are accurately reflected within the positions utilized by line renderer. A suggested modification to rectify such an updating issue is included below:

```
void Update()
{
    Physics.autoSimulation = false;

    Debug.Log("START SIMULATION");

    ghostRocketObj.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position;
    Rigidbody2D ghostVelocity = ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    ghostVelocity.velocity = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;

    List<Vector3> pathPoints = new List<Vector3>();

    for (int i = 0; i < simulationSteps; i++)
    {
        Gravity.calculateGravity(ghostPlanetsObj, ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(), true);
        TrajectoryPhysicsScene.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        pathPoints.Add(ghostRocketObj.transform.position);
    }

    lineRenderer.positionCount = simulationSteps;

    // Update the positions of the line renderer with the simulated path points
    for (int i = 0; i < simulationSteps; i++)
    {
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, pathPoints[i]);
    }

    Debug.Log("END SIMULATION");

    Physics.autoSimulation = true;
}
```

After simulating the physics and collecting the path points, we have modified the code to iterate over these points, finally setting them as positions for the line renderer by means of SetPosition method.

It is important to ensure that you have properly configured the Line Renderer component on your script's attached game object. This includes making sure it displays proper material and settings in order for its trajectory line to display correctly.

Thoroughly implementing these changes will allow the line renderer to accurately follow your rocket's trajectory in a space simulation game.|

But this is only my opinion and was not tested. You may run into the same problem again or another problem will be spotted.

EDIT:

The revised code involves grabbing the ghost rocket component's rigidbody (as ghostRocketRb) and updating its position via MovePosition, ensuring seamless movement management by the physics engine.

```
void Update()
{
    Physics.autoSimulation = false;

    Debug.Log("START SIMULATION");

    Rigidbody2D ghostRocketRb = ghostRocketObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    ghostRocketRb.MovePosition(gameObject.transform.position);
    ghostRocketRb.velocity = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;

    List<Vector3> pathPoints = new List<Vector3>();

    for (int i = 0; i < simulationSteps; i++)
    {
        Gravity.calculateGravity(ghostPlanetsObj, ghostRocketRb, true);
        TrajectoryPhysicsScene.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        pathPoints.Add(ghostRocketRb.transform.position);
    }

    lineRenderer.positionCount = simulationSteps;

    // Update the positions of the line renderer with the simulated path points
    for (int i = 0; i < simulationSteps; i++)
    {
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, pathPoints[i]);
    }

    Debug.Log("END SIMULATION");

    Physics.autoSimulation = true;
}
```

If you test this change within a simulation, you'll notice that the object used to showcase trajectory follows along with the rocket flawlessly. This makes it easier for accurate drawing of the line.|

Comment: Thank you for you posrt, but sadly the modification you suggested doesn't work.
What I noticed is the gameobject used to draw the trajectory doesn't move within the simulation and keep the same coordonates.

Comment: @CromSoldier, if you have the same problem still, look up in edit from my previous post. I might got a better idea of the problem now. If you solved the problem, please let me know what you did to solve it. ^^

Comment: So I changed the `ghostRocketObj.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position;` by the modification you suggested and now the position of `ghostRocketRb` doesn't change (it keeps the original one). I think there is an issue with the simulation's settings.